# If an Exception happens within a using statement does the object still get disposed?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, using

If an Exception happens within a using statement does the object still get disposed?

The reason why I'm asking is because I'm trying to decide on whether to put a try caught around the whole code block or within the inner using statement. Bearing in mind certain exceptions are being re-thrown by design within the catch block.

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(url))
{
   // Get the Web
   using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
   {
       // Exception occurs here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, they will.

```
using(SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
{
  // Some Code
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
  SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb();
  try
  {

    // Some Code
  }
  finally
  {
    if (spWeb != null)
    {
       spWeb.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit

After answering this question, I wrote a more in depth post about the [IDisposable and Using](http://coding.abel.nu/2011/12/idisposable-and-using-in-c/) construct in my blog.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. A `using` statement translates to approximately the following construct:

```
IDisposable x;
try
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    x.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes it does.  It's like wrapping your code in a try-finally (and disposing in the finally).

Answer (score 2):

The `using` statement causes a complete and proper `dispose` pattern to be generated, so the answer is yes.