# Handle Exception that happens within a using statement (IDisposable)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, datareader

I'm using the [DataWriter and DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208119) interfaces.
These classes have the IDisposable interface implemented, therefore I wrap them around the `using` keyword:

```
using(var datareader = new DataReader(SerialPortInputStream))
{
CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
//Timeout
cancellation.CancelAfter(1000);
//...
datareader.LoadAsync(120).AsTask(cancellation.Token);
//Some fancy methods
...
//Last step: Detach the InputStream to use it again
datareader.DetachStream();
}
```

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309877/if-an-exception-happens-within-a-using-statement-does-the-object-still-get-dispo) is saying that if an Exception (here a `"TaskCancelledException"` happens inside a using statement, the object gets disposed. Now, the problem is with the UWP-`DataReader` and `DataWriter`: They will close the underlying stream if the object gets disposed. To prevent that I've to call datareader.DetachStream() and then dispose.

*We cannot use the DataReader/DataWriter with a `using` statement when we need the underlying InputStream/Outputstream later again.*
Is this conclusion correct or are there other ways to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole meaning of `using` is to make sure that the object gets disposed at the end of the block no matter what happens without having to write all the code for this by yourself. This is done by disposing the object inside a `finally` block.

What you are trying to do is to call `datareader.DetachStream()` *before* the object gets disposed - again *no matter what happens*.

So my conclusion would be that the `using` statement isn't very helpful here and you should do this by yourself, maybe like this:

```
DataReader datareader = null;
try
{
    datareader = new DataReader(SerialPortInputStream);
    CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //Timeout
    cancellation.CancelAfter(1000);
    //...
    datareader.LoadAsync(120).AsTask(cancellation.Token);
    //Some fancy methods
    ...
}
finally
{
    //Last step: Detach the InputStream to use it again
    datareader?.DetachStream();
    datareader?.Dispose();
}
```

So this is essentially what the `using` statement does to your code, except that you can insert the `datareader?.DetachStream()` call.

---

**Note** that the `datareader` would eventually get disposed anyway even without the `using` statement. When the scope of this variable is left, the garbage collection may anytime decide to remove this instance from memory which would lead to a call to its `Dispose` method. So a call to `DetachStream()` is needed before leaving the scope.

Comment: (Regarding your note:) I've learned it the hard way. Especially when you have to use the stream again: "Suddenly" the garbage collector will close the stream and  "destroying" your other method: No matter what happens always call  `DetachStream()`.